# Python - having problems with running multiple commands in one subprocess.call

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with python trying to run multiple commands in one subprocess call.

This is my code:

```
import subprocess, sys, time

print ("Python OS 1.0")
print ("Using Python",sys.version)

livecommand = input(">>")

output = subprocess.call(livecommand,'time.sleep(10000.00)',shell=True)

print (output)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\John\Desktop\OS\FILES\console.py", line 8, in 
>       output = subprocess.call(livecommand,'time.sleep(10000.00)',shell=True)   File
>   "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 267, in call
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:   File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 607, in **init**
>       raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer") TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Comment: If you provide a second argument to `subprocess.call()`, it must be an integer (bufsize).  Instead you are passing the string `'time.sleep(10000.00)`'.  What did you intend this string to do?

Comment: I intended the string to pause and display the output of the command entered in the user input (livecommand)

Comment: `time.sleep()` looks like python code, not a system command...

Comment: I know but I thought the subprocess ran python commands but I'm still a noob with python so